# Ionic cache service npm

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic3, npm-scripts

I was trying to implement Ionic cache service to my Ionic3 project. I have followed this tutorial [Ionic Cache using npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-cache). But when I run ionic serve it throws below error.

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at CacheService.watchNetworkInit (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:81192:78)
at new CacheService (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:81074:14)
at buildCacheService (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:148296:12)
at _callFactory (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:11645:20)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:11595:26)
at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:11577:17)
at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:12814:16)
at resolveDep (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:13304:45)
at createClass (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:13174:32)
at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:13011:37)
```

can anyone help what I am missing or anything need to be added.

Below are Ionic details.

```
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.1
Angular Core: 5.2.11
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
Node: 6.9.1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Many time this problem come from plugin dependencies , you need to upgrade or downgrade your plugin for yours ionic version.

Comment: I tried to go downgrade ionic cache service version 4 to 3.0, 2.0 but still the issue is same. I can't downgrade or upgrade Ionic version, with the same version I like to continue. Is there any other way to fix it.

Comment: Do you have any dependencies warning when you install the plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to downgrade the version of the plugin, the last version of it is 4.0.1, I tried to downgrade the version to 3.1.3 it's work 100%
my ionic version is 3.9